# WordPress: How can I add extra classes via variables when using body_class()?

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I am trying to add some dynamically (based on the URI) created class names into the standard `body_class()` statement.

The wordpress codex mentions to put the class into the brackets while using the `body_class('add-class-here')`

however I have 2 variables that I need to echo out inside the `body class=""` so I tried doing it as follows:

```
<?php
$url = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$dir = $url[2] ? $url[2] : 'home';
$subdir = $url[3] ? $url[3] : '';
?>

<body <?php body_class(<?=$dir?><?=($subdir?' ':'')?><?=$subdir?>); ?>>
```

This however results in a PHP error thus breaking the page.

I tried to add `body_class($dir)` and while it works, when adding the second variable `$subdir` it fails.

eg. `body_class($dir($subdir?' ':'')$subdir)` results in:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

the `($subdir?' ':'')` is only there to add a space between class names if `$subdir` is set.

Any ideas how I can add my variables into the body class while keeping the standard generated classes of the `body_class()` function?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$path = (isset($subdir) && !empty($subdir)) 
  ? $dir . ' ' . $subdir 
  : $dir . $subdir;
body_class($path);
```

Comment: Thank you! It did indeed fix it. Thanks again.